# Pattern matching for list, capturing "...rest" elements

Tags: dart, pattern-matching

I'm new to Dart. I want to do this:

```
var list = [1, 2, 3, 4];
switch (list) {
  case [var a, var b, var ...rest]:
    // use a, b, rest
  default: ...
}
```

It doesn't like the `var ...rest` part, this syntax is not accepted. But is there any syntax to allow me to capture this?

Yet I can do this:

```
  case [_, _, ...]:
    var [a, b, ...rest] = list;
```

But it looks like a language limitation if the destructuring pattern can work in assignment but not in the switch.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax are:

```dart
  var list = [1, 2, 3, 4];
  switch (list) {
    case [var a, var b, ...var rest]:
      print('$a, $b and the $rest'); // 1, 2 and the [3, 4]
  }
```